# What does this expression evaluate to?

Tags: java, operators

```
Class Wrapper{

  psvm(){

  Integer i=new Integer(5);
  Float f=new Float(5);

  }
}
```

if `(i==f && i.equals(f))`// 1st expression evaluates to ????  and second expression evaluates to ???

```
 System.out.println("i == f returns " + (i == f) + " and equals returns " + i.equals(f));
```

Comment: What are you asking exactly?

Comment: Why you do not try it?

Comment: You have a print statement. why not use that?

Comment: i want to know how  == and equals works in this case?

Comment: @Rahul in which language?  This question is tagged Java.

Comment: but they are type incompatible na?

Comment: Yeah, the capital C on Class was there just to fool you.

Comment: @SagarByali In Java1.7 the code does not compile: `Incompatible operand types Integer and Float`. So the statement can not be evaluated.

Comment: .equals returns false if object types are different

Comment: @SagarByali - Why don't you add this line to your program?  `System.out.println("i == f returns " + (i == f) + " and equals returns " + i.equals(f));` - then you'll know the answer for sure.

Comment: == Compiler error if oprand cast are incompatible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, the test

```
if (i==f && i.equals(f))
```

is nonsensical. Since `i` is an `Integer` and `f` is a `Float`, they will never be `==` (and, since they are incommensurate types, cannot legally be compared with `==`). For reference types, the `==` operator evaluates to `true` only if the variables reference the same object, which they cannot do with objects of different types. Consequently, since `i==f` evaluates to `false`, the second part will never be evaluated because the `&&` operator is a "short circuit" boolean operator.

I suppose if `i` and `f` were of some other type, this might be a way to check that the class's `equals()` method was reflexive (as required by the spec, but there are always programming bugs). However, it would make more sense to have:

```
if (i != null && i.equals(f))
```

to avoid a potential `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Object a=new Object("sag"); Object b=new Object("sag");      System.out.println("a == b returns " + (a == b) + " and equals returns " + a.equals(b));   Is the Answer: FALSE, FALSE ?? Correct

Comment: @SagarByali - Yes. Since `a` and `b` are distinct objects, `a==b` evaluates to `false`. The implementation of `equals()` provided by the `Object` class is simply to return the result of `==`, so that will return `false` as well.

Answer (score -1):

```
String a=new String("sag"); 
String b=new String("sag"); 

System.out.println("a == b returns " +(a == b)+ " and equals returns " + a.equals(b));
```

Is the Answer: FALSE, TRUE ?? Correct

Comment: a == b returns false and equals returns true

Comment: A question is not an answer, and neither is the word 'correct' when used ambiguously.